# why the php tag gives a parse error?

Tags: php

I have an urldecoded string in a form:

```
<input type="text" name="subject" value="<?= urldecode($_GET['subject']) ?>" />
```

This gives me an error:

```
<input type="text" name="subject" value="<?php= urldecode($_GET['subject']) ?>" />
```

Also this gives an error: (space after

```
<input type="text" name="subject" value="<? = urldecode($_GET['subject']) ?>" />
```

Can someone explain me why this gives an error?
I thouhgt

```
<?
```

or

```
<?php
```

are the same and why is not a space allowed after

```
 <?
```

Comment: *"This gives me an error:"* - Being? *parse error?* knew it.

Comment: <?php= urldecode, removing the "=" would do

Answer (score 3):

Delete the "=" between the php tag and add echo

```
 <input type="text" name="subject" value="<?php echo urldecode($_GET['subject']); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

> Remove = Sign after `<?php`

```
 <?php echo urldecode($_GET['subject']) ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first is the only correct PHP tag.

The second in not correct - you would instead use `<?php echo '...' ?>`

The third is also incorrect because the opening tag has a space, therefor the PHP engine will interperet the "=" symbol as an operator in the code, which will yield a syntax error.

Hence, use either `<?= '...' ?>` or `<?php echo '...' ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with

```
<input type="text" name="subject" value="<?php echo urldecode($_GET['subject']) ?>" />
```

only if short tags are enabled

```
<input type="text" name="subject" value="<?= urldecode($_GET['subject']) ?>" />
```